# Installed language pack for magento, but getting error on Current Configuration Scope 404 page not found

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration, language

Installed language pack for magento, but getting error on Current Configuration Scope 404 page not found. However I have all 3 languages also don't work and getting the same message every time.

Please see images for the steps and error occur when clicking on current configuration scope from dropdown list.

[image: admin 404 error]

Answer (score 2):

The problem does not seem to be the language itself but a new configuration section that has been added by your language pack. You need to log out and log in again after installing extensions with new configuration sections or admin menu entries to reload your access permissions (ACL)

Yes, this is annoying, so I wrote a small extension [AclReload](https://github.com/schmengler/AclReload) that adds a "Reload ACL" link on these 404 pages which you can use instead of logging out and in.